# How to initialize the setting in wallpaper app in android?

Tags: java, android

1. Im making wallpaper app which it has a setting button for users which could adjust how many circle can be drawn on the wallpaper. Here i set 5 as default value in the preferences.xml . When i install the app,the wallpaper constructor get the number of circles in preference.xml which just 0 and i have to manually press setting button and set the number. So I want the keep the number is 5 ( default) when installing the app.
2. Some class that use for the App:
   preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <EditTextPreference android:key="numofparticles" android:title="Number of particles" android:summary="Chose a initial particle's number" android:defaultValue="5">

    </EditTextPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Prefernces.java

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
    public static String numofparticles="numofparticles";
    public static String image="getimage";
    private static final int Pic_image=1;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener PreferenceChangeListener;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        

        PreferenceChangeListener=new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
                if (s.equals(numofparticles) && s.getClass().getSimpleName()=="Interger")
                {
                    Preference numofP=findPreference(s);
                    numofP.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(s,"")+ " Particles");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }

            }
        };
```

Snippet from another class which i get this preference data.

```
public wallpaperengine()
        {
            display.getRealSize(size);
            wallpaper_height=size.y;
            wallpaper_width=size.x;
            background=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.particlebackground);
            background=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(background,wallpaper_width,wallpaper_height,true);


            sharedPreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(particlewallpaper.this);
            sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
            num_particle=Integer.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getString(Preferences.numofparticles,"5"));

            handler.post(drawFrames);
        }
```

Comment: `here is no preference file in the path data/data/package/shared_prefs.` Indeed. Not in the beginning. But when the user uses your preference activity and changes values then it will be created automatically bij Andoid OS.

Comment: But.... There is no problem description in your post. Nor a question. Please edit your post to make your problem clear.

Comment: `Here is the code: preferences.xml` The code? You mean: `Here is the layout file for my activity: preferences.xml`

Comment: `How to setup and use Shared Preference in android?` You should also realize that for using shared preferences your app does not need to present a preference activity (with a layout file). An app can use shared preferences without that all. Please edit your post to show what you mean with `use shared preferences`.

Comment: No, sorry its not clear. This is some class that i use for the App. To be clearly, im making wallpaper app and this is Preference class that for Setting .

Comment: Then now  please write your problem description and questions. (In your post)

Comment: In the wallpaperengine() constructor i get the data form the preference which is should be 5 as i decleare in the xml. But it not works. the user have to press the button Setting and set the number.

Comment: I editted the post, u can check again.

Comment: `Here i set 5 as default value. ` Where? Which statement? Please write a post so we understand what you want and do as this is abacadabra

Comment: `Here i set 5 as default value in the preferences.xml .` Please edit that block as now  have to scroll half an hour to finally see `android:defaultValue="5"`. And why dont you mention that?

Comment: `preferences.xml` Please rename to `preferences_layout.xml` As it is confusing as the name of the file in /data/data/package/shared_prefs would be `package_preferences.xml`

Comment: Are you talking about `num_particle=Integer.valueOf(sharedPreferences.getString(Preferences.numofparticles,"5"));` ?

Answer (score 0):

The default 5 is in the layout file (which resides in xml folder of AS) for your preferences activity.

Not in the real preferences data file which resides in /data/data/package/shared_prefs/package_preferences.xml.

The wallpaper code reads from the real data file.

Not from the layout file.

And you know that that activity and layout file are not needed 'to work with shared preferences'.

Comment: I see ur point. It works. Thanks